# How to find how much time has elapsed in C++ using sys/times.h

Tags: c++, timer

I want to do something like the following:

```
get t1
run a program
get t2
display t2 - t1
```

Basically I'm trying to find out how much time a program used. I have seen several solutions to this, but the one I like is the one where `sys/times.h` is used, but haven't quite figured it out. How can this be done?

Comment: If you are using Linux or any other Unix flavor, the `time` command does what you want:  `time program args...`

Comment: is it a command-line program? linux?

Comment: @wallyk it is precisely what i had in mind..

Comment: I know about the time command. Actually I am trying to do something a little more complicated. I need to do use `sys/times.h`.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct timeval timeStart,timeEnd;
int error1=gettimeofday(&timeStart, NULL);
//stuff you want to measure goes here
int error2=gettimeofday(&timeEnd, NULL);
if(error1 || error2) return -1; //some error occured

//this gives the result in microseconds.
return (timeEnd.tv_sec - timeStart.tv_sec)*1000000.0+(timeEnd.tv_usec - timeStart.tv_usec);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use , which is cross-platform (I don't know if that matters to you).
It would be simple: you can use the clock() function, which returns an integer. There is a macro called CLOCKS_PER_SEC that tells you how many clock pulses there will be in 1 second in the current machine. In C code, that would be:

```
#include <time.h>

unsigned old_clock = clock();
unsigned current_clock = 0;//will be assigned later
//do anything you want to time
current_clock = clock();
printf("%d seconds (%d milliseconds) ellapsed.\n", (current_clock - old_clock) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC, (current_clock - old_clock) / (CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000) );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using windows, look into QueryPerformanceCounter and QueryPerformanceFrequency. They are available after you include windows.h

Comment: And why the down votes? The question doesn't say linux OR windows... Since there were linux solutions...i provided the basis for a windows one...

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/times.h>
int main()
{
    time_t clkTimeBegin, clkTimeEnd;
    time(&clkTimeBegin);
    std::cout<<"Run your program here"<<std::endl;
    time(&clkTimeEnd);
    std::cout << "Time diff, " << difftime(clkTimeBegin, clkTimeEnd ) << "!\n"; 
}
```